# std::log vs MATLAB's log for complex numbers

Tags: c++, matlab, std

I was comparing the implementations of an algorithm in C++ and MATLAB.
While debugging I found that the `std::log` and MATLAB's `log` don't seem to return the same value.

the concrete example is

```
X   = (0.98624334784190482,0.019377216547938527)
```

I am getting that

```
std::log(std::complex<double>(0.98624334784190482,0.019377216547938527))
```

gives

```
(-0.013659176853856606,0.019644972824447767)
```

while in MATLAB the log of the same complex number is

```
(-0.013659176853856606, 0.019644972824447764)
```

---

I have two questions.

1) Is it correct that these two functions are giving me different answers? How can I know? I think I know (using `union` of a `double` and a `uint64_t`) or can find out easily how to see the underlying binary representations of the input and results in C++, but I am not sure about how to do it in MATLAB. [OK. Found something that might serve for this part](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79319-double-to-binary-representation-not-using-dec2bin)

OK. this part seems to be solved. I did `typecast(imag(log(X)), 'uint64');` and it prints

4581319499315104670 in MATLAB

while in C++ the trick with the `union` gives

4581319499315104671

So, I guess that confirms that the imaginary parts of the results are different.

2) If it is true that these two implementations of logarithms are not equivalent, how can I approach building a MATLAB implementation that matches `std::log`. Maybe just a starting point is enough, like what to do to find out the implementation of `std::log` that I am using?

So far on this one I have found that the imaginary part of std::log is computed (as expected) as

```
// 26.2.7/4: arg(__z): Returns the phase angle of __z.
template<typename _Tp>
inline _Tp
__complex_arg(const complex<_Tp>& __z)
{ return  atan2(__z.imag(), __z.real()); }
```

and

```
  inline _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR long double
  atan2(long double __y, long double __x)
  { return __builtin_atan2l(__y, __x); }
```

Now I need to find the implementation of `__builtin_atan2l`.

I noticed that MATLAB has an `atan2` function by computing `atan2(imag(X), real(Y))` I get the same value as the imaginary parts above. So I guess MATLAB also implements `log` similar to `std::log` by computing the imaginary part by calling `atan2(y,x)`. The funny thing is that the atan2 is giving different results in C++ and in MATLAB.

---

**Notes:** Using gcc-4.8.4 for rhel-x86_64-5.2 and MATLAB 2011b for 64 bits both.

Comment: what compiler are you using ?

Comment: @ВиталикБушаев Added that to the question.

Comment: Looking at text representations of floating-point values is always a bit iffy. You don't generally know what they're doing with the low-order bits when converting to decimal, so differences way out at the ends may or may not be meaningful. The way to test for equality is to test for equality of the **values**, not of something derived from those values.

Comment: @PeteBecker I think I found how to look at the binary representation in both MATLAB and C++. Added it to the question.

Comment: Why do you need them to be the same? There is no requirement in the floating point spec that such calculations should give the same result. Different languages, libraries, compilers, etc. will often not return identical results for some inputs. Matlab's functions incorporate a lot more numeric sophistication than C/C++ standard library versions.

Comment: And if you do want the same output, I suggest writing a [MEX file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/write-cc-mex-files.html) to perform the relevant calculation in C++.

Comment: @horchler I understand that they don't have to be the same, but I need them to be the same. Sorry, but the reasons I need them to be the same are long to explain, but don't worry they are not very relevant to the question, they are closer to bureaucracy than to logic. The idea of using those MEX files might be my way out. Thanks. I didn't know they existed.

Comment: @horchler I computed the relevant arctangent (or complex logarithm) to 100 exact digits. It is actually MATLAB the one that gets the last bit *wrong*. MATLAB's result has a zero as the last bit, while the exact result should have a 1 in binary. I will try to talk to them to see why is that, if it is a bug or if they are using the last bit for something else.